# ¿Cómo puedo crear archivos con un número que incremente dependiendo de si existe uno con el mismo nombre?

Tags: java

Me encuentro haciendo un proyecto para la universidad de un sistema de facturación, que al efectuar una compra, debe crear una factura en formato .txt, el problema radica en que necesito que el nombre de las facturas se vaya incrementando con un número para identificarlas correctamente. he intentado de todo, pero siempre que ejecuto, al realizar la compra, la factura generada reemplaza a la anterior.

```java
private void guardaTabla(){
    try {
        int numero = 0; 
        String facturaFile = "src/factura/factura_"+numero+".txt";
        File fileFactura = new File(facturaFile);

        if (!fileFactura.exists()){
            BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(facturaFile));
            bfw.write("--------FACTURA--------"); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Nombre: " + lblNombreCliente.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Cedula: " + lblCedula.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Nro. Tlf: " + lblTelefonoCliente.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("------------------------"); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("IdEmp: " + lblIdEmp.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Nombre Empleado: " + lblNombreEmp.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("------------------------"); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Fecha: " + txtFecha.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write(""); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("--------PRODUCTOS--------"); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Id       Nombre       Descripcion     Cantidad     Precio     Importe:"); bfw.newLine();

            for (int i = 0 ; i < jTableVenta.getRowCount(); i++) { //realiza un barrido por filas.
                for(int j = 0 ; j < jTableVenta.getColumnCount();j++) { //realiza un barrido por columnas.
                    bfw.write((String)(jTableVenta.getValueAt(i,j)));
                    if (j < jTableVenta.getColumnCount() -1) { //agrega separador
                        bfw.write("  -  ");
                    }
                }
                bfw.newLine(); //inserta nueva linea.
            } 

            /*Precio*/
            bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Precio Total: \n"
                    + txtPrecio.getText() + ".bfs");

            bfw.close(); //cierra archivo!

        } else {
            numero++;
            facturaFile = "src/factura/factura_"+numero+".txt";

            BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(facturaFile));

            bfw.write("--------FACTURA--------"); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Nombre: " + lblNombreCliente.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Cedula: " + lblCedula.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Nro. Tlf: " + lblTelefonoCliente.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("------------------------"); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("IdEmp: " + lblIdEmp.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Nombre Empleado: " + lblNombreEmp.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("------------------------"); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Fecha: " + txtFecha.getText()); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write(""); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("--------PRODUCTOS--------"); bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Id       Nombre       Descripcion     Cantidad     Precio     Importe:"); bfw.newLine();

            for (int i = 0 ; i < jTableVenta.getRowCount(); i++) { //realiza un barrido por filas.
                for(int j = 0 ; j < jTableVenta.getColumnCount();j++) { //realiza un barrido por columnas.
                    bfw.write((String)(jTableVenta.getValueAt(i,j)));
                    if (j < jTableVenta.getColumnCount() -1) { //agrega separador
                        bfw.write("  -  ");
                    }
                }
                bfw.newLine(); //inserta nueva linea.
            } 

            /*Precio*/
            bfw.newLine();
            bfw.write("Precio Total: \n"
                    + txtPrecio.getText() + ".bfs");

            bfw.close(); //cierra archivo!
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se ha creado la factura satisfactoriamente.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No se ha podido crear una factura.");
    }
}
```

Este es el código que estoy manejando para tratar de lograr mi cometido, pero a pesar de todo solo he llegado a hacer 2 archivos (factura_0.txt y factura_1.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Deberias usar la clase Formatter y si el archivo ya existe, extenderlo en vez de sobreescribirlo.

Ejemplo en codigo de la clase:

```
package LeerGrabar;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class ArchivoGrabacion {

private Formatter out;

public ArchivoGrabacion(String unNombre) {
    try {
        
        out = new Formatter(unNombre);
    
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No se puede crear.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public ArchivoGrabacion(String unNombre, boolean ext) {
    //Si el parametro viene en true, indica que se extiende el archivo.
    //Si es false, se sobreescribe.
    try {
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(unNombre, ext);
        out = new Formatter(f);
        
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No se puede crear/extender.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public void grabarLinea(String linea) {
    out.format("%s%n", linea);
}

public void cerrar() { 
    out.close();
}}
```

De esta forma, cuando llames para crear el archivo, como parametro en el metodo "ArchioGrabacion", ademas del nombre, le pasas el valor "true", de esta forma, si el archivo no existe lo crea y si el archivo existe, lo extiende.